# Should backend require a "user_id" along with the Refresh Token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

Is it safer to have the client send an additional field like their "user_id" alongside their Refresh Token? This way the server could retrieve data using both fields, making it harder for a malicious user to target *any* refresh token (since they'd have to match a specific pair).

I feel like I remember reading something similar on the oauth2 rfc.